# Upgrading from 12.10 to 13.10

Tags: 12.04, 13.10

I want to upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10 but i had question when upgrading does the data get removed or should we make backup of it or can we install just like that

Answer (score 0):

> I want to upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10

Direct distribution upgade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10 is not possible.But you can upgrade Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.10 through Ubuntu 13.10 live disk.

> does the data get removed or should we make backup of it

Yes your data's will be  lost if you don't have a seperate `/home` partition.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the installer does not go wrong or encounter an issue, you should not lose any data, everything in /home should be untouched.  However, you should as a good practice backup your data on a regular basis, and always before a major system change.